# Handle large number of asynchronous calls in java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am designing a reminder (with thousands of users). When time's up, reminder needs to remind user with the message.

One possible solution is to create a new thread and wait for that thread to run till reminder's time and then send the message to that particular user.

It can be done using `ScheduledExecutorService` or Java Timer.

Is there any better approach than creating a new thread and waiting until time's up and then terminate the thread.

Comment: Maybe you should look in RxJava. It will help you handle loads and loads of async calls with minimal effort. http://reactivex.io/

Comment: Have you tried using JMS? I think this can solve your problem.

Comment: see this may help you https://vertx.io/

Comment: @Seaskyways will check RxJava. Looks interesting.

Comment: @DKAnsh I am aware of JMS but how can it be used to send/recieve msg at a particular time?

Comment: @AkashShah will explore vertx

Comment: @AkashShah looks relevent - https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/future/ComposeExample.java

Comment: take a look of  `java.util.concurrent.Future` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use one thread. And another pool of threads for sending messages (for not to slow down the main thread). You need to put reminder's time in order and for each reminder's time have a list of corresponding users. Main thread fall asleep until the next reminder's time, than wake up and notify users who correspond to this reminder's time.

But this approach has its drawbacks. For example, you need to solve the problem: what to do with adding users? If they add reminder's time between the present moment and the next moment when the main thread wakes up. Wake up the main thread or use a reserve thread for this purpose.

Comment: I think this approach will not be useful for short duration reminders.

Comment: @devツ, yes. It depends on the actual conditions of the problem. But I think that the simpler is the better. Also try looking at the schedulers libraries. But grouped by time, so as not to produce thousands of threads. Maybe http://www.quartz-scheduler.org. He works with thread pool. We use it as a scheduler for our tasks (only a few dozen tasks). But I do not know if it is suitable for your task. And I think that the sending of messages can be a bottleneck for short duration reminders.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Event Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) pattern. It was especially created for the [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).
For the implementation you may take a look at the [Vert.x](https://vertx.io). Vert.x's event loop is in fact classical event loop that waits for events that are handle concurrently by delivering these events to the appropriate service handler.
All verticles (You can think of a verticle as an asynchronous vert.x service) communicate with each other through the Event Bus that forms a distributed peer-to-peer messaging system spanning multiple server nodes and multiple browsers.

[Vert.X tutorial](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/)  has fine explanation of this topic and will help you write your own asynchronous services.

Comment: C10k problem link correct?

Comment: @devツ sry, fixed

Comment: It looks relevant to my problem. I'll check more on this.

Comment: @devツ also I'll recommend you not waste you time trying to write callbacks-based code (because it looks really ugly when number of callbacks is increasingly growing) and go with vertx-rxjava2 module.